# Find modular arithmetic within a range.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

When we execute any modular arithmetic say $a \pmod n$ then it results $0$ to $n-1$. But I need to find out a result within a range say $m$ to $n-1$. Is it possible? If then how?

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1, n=12, m=4$, what answer do you want to $1 \pmod {12}$?  You can do $a \pmod {n-m}$ getting an answer in $[0,n-m-1]$, then add $m$ to the result to get an answer in $[m,n-1]$  In my example the answer would then be $5$.